# How can I securely access a Rackspace Cloud Database in AWS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database, rackspace

Rackspace limits access for Cloud Databases to their ServiceNet. How can I securely and efficiently connect to a database instance there from AWS (over the public internet)?

Comment: IPSec, SSH tunnel, etc.

Comment: Would a simple SSH port binding type of setup be sufficient?

Comment: If by port binding you mean port forwarding, perhaps. Depends on your requirements. For ad-hoc connections, it's probably ok. For long-term usage, though, IPSec is the way to go. Of course, it goes without saying that having your DB and application separated like this is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: IPSec sounds like it might be the right fit. It wouldn't be for primary application usage. Looking at options for migrating data elegantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Cloud Load Balancer to access your Cloud Database over public internet.

[Here](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/connect-to-a-cloud-databases-instance#lb) is a link to the documentation

[Here](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-ssl-with-your-cloud-database-instance) is a link to the documentation if you want to use SSL

> **Note:** Do not add additional nodes behind the load balancer. If you require HA or replication you can create an HA group, or add a replica
>   in your Cloud Control Panel.

Comment: Does enabling SSL on the database instance require all connections to be over SSL? Or does it just make it available in addition?

Comment: SSL is already enabled, you just need to use it. I suggest taking a moment and reading the SSL documentation: 

"You can also set up restrictions on a *user* to require SSL when communicating with the database. MySQL supports the GRANT statement modifier REQUIRE SSL. For example, to restrict database_user to have read, write, and delete permissions for prod_database only when connected with an SSL connection, log in to MySQL as root and then issue the following command..."